# Photos are deleted from the app after a short period of time automatically in android 11

Tags: android, android-studio

Why does Android 11 delete photos from the program automatically after a short period of time even though I use the program constantly and all permissions are accepted
i use this code for create a folder that store photos

```
 public static File pcsfoldr(Context contxt){ return new File( contxt.getExternalFilesDir(null), "pictures" ); }
```

and granted this permissions

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

and in application

```
 android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
```

**this image with pictures**
[image]

**and this without pictures**
[image]

can you tell me the reason please

Comment: Sorry, but i do not believe that. What exactly happens?

Comment: every thing works fine but after some dayes the pictures does not exist in the app and i enter with an file manager app i found no images !

Comment: Normal FileManager apps on Android 11+ can never see the files which your app put in getExternalFilesDir() (and your app does not need any permission to do so)  as that location is private to your app.

Comment: `the pictures does not exist in the app` ??? What do you mean? Picture files reside on the storage of your device. Not in apps.  Where are you talking about?

Comment: i use an advansed file manager app it shows all files in android/data folder and all apps files i edit the Q with images clear my isuses

Comment: In order to check if files created in getExternalFilesDir("pictures") by your app are still there after a time you should use File.listFiles() instead of an external application. Please do and tell. And you do not need any permission or ask for legacy external storage. Please react on this!

Comment: `it shows all files in android/data` You mean in /storage/emulated/0/Android/data folder? Why does your file manager not even show that Android folder? And what would be Main storage? Not very clear. Not very informative.

Comment: `use an advansed file manager app` Well tell which one please.

Comment: used File.listFiles() in my app and no pictures found

Comment: Remove that app from your device and see that no longer files are removed. Are you cleaning caches for your app ? Or what are you messing around for the rest?

Comment: the file manager https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.alphainventor.filemanager&hl=en_US&gl=US

Comment: i downloaded the file manager app after problem found to check if files exist or not